# Java OQL find paths between two objects

Tags: visualvm, oql

With that Spring Boot auto-configuration and a lot of jars under the umbrella I had many contexts loaded and my configuration somehow ignored.

I made heapdump and would like to find paths between two known objects. That helps me to identify what context responsible for object.

How I can find paths between two objects in Java heapdump with OQL?